# All Input Fields Uploading in Database Well except File in Php/Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I m posting html form using php and storing data in mysql database, but unfortunately, all the fields are storing in database except, file one. 
And when we submit form, it give us alert message like "Successfully Added !!!" and on back page, it give us the message like "undifined index pro_file", why ??

**OUTPUT**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF7yZ.png)

**academic_work_add.php**

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="academic_work_post.php">

                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                                            Add Academic Work
                                        </h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="row_detail">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Student Name
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="student_email" class="form-control" id="student_email" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { echo $_SESSION['user']; } ?>" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dayInput">
                                                        Category
                                                    </label>
                                                    <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">

                                                    <?php

                                                    $query ="SELECT * from categories";
$run =mysqli_query($con,$query);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {

    $name=$row[1];

                                                         echo "<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
                                }
                                                    ?>


                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Title
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Description
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Pages
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="pages" class="form-control" id="pages" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Grade
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="grade" class="form-control" id="grade" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Name of Processor
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="name_processor" class="form-control" id="name_processor" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Prices
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="price" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Discount Percent
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="discount_percent" class="form-control" id="discount_percent" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        Payment Commission
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="payment_commission" class="form-control" id="payment_commission" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dateInput">
                                                        File
                                                    </label>
                                    <input required type="file" name="filefield" id="filefield" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                                    <label for="dayInput">
                                                        Status
                                                    </label>
                                                    <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">

                                                         <option value='Active'>Active</option>
                                                            <option value='Inactive'>Inactive</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                </div>

            </div>
                            <center><input id="submit"  name="submit" type="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" value="Submit"></center>
                            </form>
```

**academic_work_post.php**

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    include_once("connection.php");
    if($_POST["submit"])
    {

    $student_email=$_POST['student_email'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $pages=$_POST['pages'];
    $grade=$_POST['grade'];
    $name_processor=$_POST['name_processor'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $discount_percent=$_POST['discount_percent'];
    $payment_commission=$_POST['payment_commission'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];

    $pro_file=$_FILES['pro_file']['name'];
    $temp_name1=$_FILES['pro_file']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"files/$pro_file");

    $sql="INSERT INTO academic_work (student_email,category,title,description,pages,grade,name_processor,price,discount_percent,payment_commission,pro_file,status,date) VALUES 
    ('$student_email','$category','$title','$description','$pages','$grade','$name_processor','$price','$discount_percent','$payment_commission','$pro_file','$status',NOW())";

    if($con->query($sql)===true)
    {

    echo "<script>window.alert('Successfully Added !!!')</script>";

    echo "<script>window.open('academic_work.php','_self')</script>";

    }
    else{
    echo "<script>window.alert('Please Try Again.')</script>";

    echo "<script>window.open('academic_work_add.php','_self')</script>";
    }
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `academic_work_add.php`:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="academic_work_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Add Academic Work</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row_detail">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Student Name
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="student_email" class="form-control" id="student_email" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { echo $_SESSION['user']; } ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dayInput">
                            Category
                        </label>
                        <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">

                            <?php
                                $query = "SELECT * from categories"; 
                                $run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) { 
                                    $name = $row[1];
                                    echo "<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
                                }
                            ?>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Title
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Description
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Pages
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="pages" class="form-control" id="pages" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Grade
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="grade" class="form-control" id="grade" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Name of Processor
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="name_processor" class="form-control" id="name_processor" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Prices
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="price" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Discount Percent
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="discount_percent" class="form-control" id="discount_percent" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            Payment Commission
                        </label>
                        <input required type="text" name="payment_commission" class="form-control" id="payment_commission" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateInput">
                            File
                        </label>
                        <input required type="file" name="filefield" id="filefield" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dayInput">
                            Status
                        </label>
                        <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
                            <option value='Active'>Active</option>
                            <option value='Inactive'>Inactive</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <center>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" value="Submit">
    </center>
</form>
```

Your `academic_work_post.php` :

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include_once("connection.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $student_email=$_POST['student_email'];
        $category=$_POST['category'];
        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $description=$_POST['description'];
        $pages=$_POST['pages'];
        $grade=$_POST['grade'];
        $name_processor=$_POST['name_processor'];
        $price=$_POST['price'];
        $discount_percent=$_POST['discount_percent'];
        $payment_commission=$_POST['payment_commission'];
        $status=$_POST['status'];


        $uploaddir = '/files/';
        $pro_file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['filefield']['name']);
        $temp_name1=$_FILES['filefield']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name1, $pro_file);


        $sql="INSERT INTO academic_work (student_email,category,title,description,pages,grade,name_processor,price,discount_percent,payment_commission,pro_file,status,date) VALUES 
        ('$student_email','$category','$title','$description','$pages','$grade','$name_processor','$price','$discount_percent','$payment_commission','$pro_file','$status',NOW())";

        if($con->query($sql)){
            echo "<script>window.alert('Successfully Added !!!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('academic_work.php','_self')</script>";
        } else{
            echo "<script>window.alert('Please Try Again.')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('academic_work_add.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks.. By the way, what was the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all set you form to `enctype="multipart/form-data"` where you define the action

Second you don't have such field `pro_file` in the form you have field with name `filefield` please change this to name="pro_file". After that try again

Comment: Tsoev, the upper one is exactly what i want... but thank u so much, for comment and trying to help.. Thanks